# Android app build is successful the app does show up on the emulator, I am using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[screen shot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzFRt.png)
I have made a basic app in andriod which was running perfect yesterday but I dont understand why is it not showing up now in emulator. I am new to andriod and andriod studio. I am unable to preview the app. Please help me.

I unstalled the Android studio then again installed it and my problem is solved...Thanks for helping...

Comment: Sorry for asking, but are you sure you pressed "run" and not only "build"

Comment: Yes I hit run...

Answer (score 0):

Successfully Building app not show up in device

You have to run the App to show up in device

Here is the documentation for [Run apps on the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator)

Comment: Yes after running it shows built successful but preview not available

Answer (score 0):

Check out these points :

1. The run/debug configuration should be App or Application, which you can find left to run icon. If there is something else like MainActivity on it click on it and select App.
2. Menu -> Tools -> Uncheck " Enable ADB Integration ".
3. If the above doesn't work try wiping out emulator data, which you can find in ADB Manager.
4. If you had added any dependency build the gradle file.